# Installing rspec-rails failing (trying to update to rails 4.0/ruby 2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, installation, rspec-rails

I am getting the following error message in the console after running

```
rails generate rspec:install

C:RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'require' : cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

followed by several more messages saying similar things, but instead of 'require', there are other messages like 'block', 'each', 'block in require', etc.

Any suggestions as to how to get this installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11208), this a problem with C compiling in Ruby 2.0.0. Try switching to Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to update ruby to 2.0.0 along with updating rails to 4.0. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/gedIaMryCFQ/discussion